# Autopep8 comment formatting in vim visual selection

Tags: python, vim, pep8

I have a similar problem to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449056/how-to-set-correct-indendation-when-using-formatprg-autopep8). I set

```
setlocal formatprg=autopep8\ --aggressive\ --aggressive\ -
```

Now when I select a long comment line in Visual Mode and press `gq`, the `autopep8` makes its modification to the line but it also alters the indentation of the line as seen in the Gif below (the line is pushed to the left).

If the visual selection is large enough to encompass the top-level indentation (i.e. where there's no indentation) or if I run autopep8 on the whole file everything is indented correctly (as seen in the second part of the Gif)

So my question is: how I can achieve the correct indentation level when formatting comments in a visual selection with `autopep8`? I tried setting:

```
setlocal formatprg=autopep8\ --aggressive\ --aggressive\ --indent-size \ 0\ -
```

but it didn't fix the problem.

[image]